# Change CSS theme in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack

Im currently working on a Angular2 application with webpack and Im trying to set differents css themes according to the user.

For example : When the user connect, If it's a boy, I want to have my backgrounds blue, and if it's a girl I want the backgrounds to be pink.

**Simply changing the css value with `setAttribute` or `style.property` wont work because the DOM is destroyed when changing tab in the application, it needs to be kinda permanent.**

I've tried using different css stylesheets (1 for each theme) and linking them to my html with javascript when the user connect. Problem is, webpack is always adding automatically my css to my html when building the app.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried to declare scope var and use ngClass ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your css, make a rule like :

```
.is-boy{
    background: blue;
}

.is-girl{
    background: pink;
}
```

and declare in you angular app a scope var like `$scope.userSex = 'boy';`

and on your body use ngClass like this

```
<body [ngClass]="{'is-boy': userSex === 'boy', 'is-girl': userSex === 'girl'}" ...
```

Comment: This looks like its working, would have been better If I could hit all elements at once since I have to put ngClass on 50+ elements :p

Comment: @Duncan you don't use sass or less ? ^^

Comment: I'm using sass but also WebPack who build the app and convert sass into css, and I need to change the theme while the app is running because I got the information 'isABoy : isAGirl' only when the user connect.

Comment: @Duncan just make a new stylesheet and encompass all rules with your class, no ?

Comment: @Duncan don't forget to click on the check button on the left if my response solve your problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

### [:host-context](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#using-component-styles) selector

You could use the `:host-context` selector to apply styles to your component based on the parent component.

```
styles:[`
    :host-context(.parent1) div{
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    :host-context(.parent2) div{
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  `]
```

This allows you to conditionally apply styles based on a the selector that wraps the component.

### [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ngSbbFE0teSLKaOTjFOx?p=preview)

edit:

So in your case - your parent would have a `div` with class **.boy** and a `div` with class **.girl**

You could load these containing divs with some flag controlled by `ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be permanent store class value in localStorage. To set the theme use ngClass with variable set to theme you need.